# Multithreading and ORMLite

Tags: multithreading, ormlite

I have a database manager class that manages access do the database. It contains the connections pool and 2 DAOs. Each for a different table. Looks something like this:

```
public class ActivitiesDatabase {
    private final ConnectionSource connectionSource;
    private final Dao<JsonActivity, String> jsonActivityDao;
    private final Dao<AtomActivity, String> atomActivityDao;

private ActivitiesDatabase() {
    try {
        connectionSource = new JdbcPooledConnectionSource(Consts.JDBC);
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, JsonActivity.class);
        jsonActivityDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, JsonActivity.class);

        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, AtomActivity.class);
        atomActivityDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, AtomActivity.class);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public long insertAtom(String id, String content) throws SQLException {
    long additionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    atomActivityDao.createIfNotExists(new Activity(id, content, additionTime));
    return additionTime;
}

public long insertJson(String id, String content) throws SQLException {
    long additionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    jsonActivityDao.createIfNotExists(new Activity(id, content, additionTime));
    return additionTime;
} 
public AtomResult getAtomEntriesBetween(long from, long to) throws SQLException {
    long updated = System.currentTimeMillis();
    PreparedQuery<Activity> query = atomActivityDao.queryBuilder().limit(500L).orderBy(Activity.UPDATED_FIELD, true).where().between(Activity.UPDATED_FIELD, from, to).prepare();
    return new Result(atomActivityDao.query(query), updated);
}

public JsonResult getJsonEntriesBetween(long from, long to) throws SQLException {
    long updated = System.currentTimeMillis();
    PreparedQuery<Activity> query = jsonActivityDao.queryBuilder().limit(500L).orderBy(Activity.UPDATED_FIELD, true).where().between(Activity.UPDATED_FIELD, from, to).prepare();
    return new Result(jsonActivityDao.query(query), updated);
}
}
```

In addition, I have two thread running using the same database manager. Each thread writes to a different table. There are also threads who read from the database. A reading thread can read from any table. 
I noticed in the ConnectionsSource documentation that it is not thread safe.

my question is. Should I synchronize the function that write to the database.
Would the answer to  my question be different if both write thread were to write to the the same table?

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed in the ConnectionsSource documentation that it is not thread safe.

Right but you are using the `JdbcPooledConnectionSource` which is thread-safe.

> Would I synchronize the function that write to the database.

You shouldn't have a problem with ORMLite doing this.  However, you need to make sure that your *database* supports multiple concurrent database updates.  For example, you won't have a problem if you are using MySQL, Postgres, or Oracle.  You'll need to read up on H2 multithreading to see what options you will need to use to get that to work.

> Would the answer to my question be different if both write thread were to write to the the same table?

That would increase the concurrency so (uh) maybe?  Again it depends on the database type.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Connection pool for multithreading working with ORMLite here is [javaDoc](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-jdbc/com/j256/ormlite/jdbc/JdbcPooledConnectionSource.html)